# Get difference for each month data

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I am having a table like below. I want to get a difference for each month (Subtract the value of last day of the month by the first date of the month).

```
========================
Date       | type| value
------------------------
01-01-2019 | A   | 10
01-02-2019 | A   | 30
31-01-2019 | A   | 40

Expected output
A -> 30
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
select diff
from
(
select abs(value-
    (select value 
    from yourtable as a2 
    where a2.date=EOMONTH(a1.date))) diff
from yourtable as a1
)
where diff is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select type, year(date), month(date),
       (max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then value end) -
        max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then value end) 
       ) as month_diff
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type, year(date), month(date) order by date) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by type, year(date), month(date) order by date desc) as seqnum_desc
      from t
     ) t
group by type, year(date), month(date);
```

If you know what the values are increasing (or non-decreasing), then you can use aggregation:

```
select type, year(date), month(date), max(value) - min(value)
from t
group by type, year(date), month(date);
```

Comment: Do you know if row_number() is available in sybase ASE?

Comment: I sybase version which I am using does not support row_number() function